# Does neo4j on android device works properly

Tags: neo4j

Has anyone successfully run a android application with neo4j as the backend.
I am really inquisitive and want to create a application using neo4j on android.
Is it possible?

By Googling I can find a blog but it is too old (2013)
Here is the blog 
http://neo4j.com/blog/new-incubator-project-neo4j-mobile-for-android-v0-1/

any progress on this?

Comment: You can store the Neo backend in somewhere and use the REST interface to query it. Embed a Neo instance on an Android device sounds interesting though.

Comment: yes but that will not work in case I am not connected to internet. I wanted a solution just like mysql-lite

Comment: hi nipun...had you find any solution for this?

Comment: No...not yet. I think it is still not achieved.